# Jekyll not finding images in root _pics folder

Tags: jekyll

I've a Jekyll site that I'm developing locally with `jekyll serve` and I'm editing a post in the `_posts` directory and I'm storing images in a `_pics` directory.

I'm trying to reference the image inline with all sorts of things...

```
../_pics/image.png
/_pics/image.png
{{ site.url }}/_pics/image.png
{{ site.url }}_pics/image.png
```

The last two really don't work, because when I inspect it, it's of course referencing my github URL, which makes no sense if I'm trying to develop locally first.

What's the right way to handle this if I want to develop locally and not have the images not break when they get pushed up to GitHub?

---

I noticed that changing the `_pics` folder to `pics` with no underscore fixed it...Not sure why that is though.  There may be a special meaning for underscore prepended folders with Jekyll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**_pics** and generally all folder beginning with underscore are ignored by jekyll.

You can instruct jekyll to process a specific "underscored" folder by adding this folder in the [`include` configuration array](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#global-configuration).

In **_config.yml**, add :

```
include :
  - _pics
```